# android studio - cannot resolve symbol "recyclerview"

Tags: android, gradle

```
cannot resolve symbol "recyclerview"
```

Just like this message I'm getting them now in every single fragment class.

My app gradle has the following:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
```

My project still runs and builds even though I have all of these errors in my classes. Any idea how to resolve? Also getting these errors in the Gradle Build (they might be related)

```
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.instabug.library.b) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.instabug.library.c) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
```

Thank you

Comment: @Javacoder it's literally calling find by view id's that are highlighted in red... what would help?

Comment: your class name is wrong,Change class RecyclerView and try again..

Comment: @Javacoder I'm sorry I don't think I understand what you mean. Can you please clarify? Thank you